# How to execute migration on selected nodes thru core bulk action plugin?

Tags: 8, nodes, migrations, actions

I'm trying to execute migration to create a copy of selected content nodes to other content type. Migration source (plugin: content_entity) is content_type_a and destination (plugin: entity) is content_type_b. My migration executed thru drush is working great for all nodes, but how to execute this migration on selected (in a view) nodes thru core bulk action plugin?

Comment: Are you're referring to bulk action via the VBO module?

Comment: @ShawnConn no, I'm refering to the plugin Action provided by Drupal core